# sass dynamic width

Tags: sass

I'm using

```
.w400 { 
  width: 400px; 
}

.w110 {
  width: 110px;
}

.w600 {
  width: 600px;
}
```

is it possible to make dynamic class with sass?

something like

```
.w(size) {
    width: size+px
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to be able to use arbitrary `.w(something)` classes, I believe (see below) that is not possible with Sass. However, if you know beforehand what sizes you need, you could use [mixins](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins) with arguments to generate the classes. Something like this:

```
@mixin width-class($size) {
  .w#{$size} {
    width: $size * 1px;
  }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
@include width-class(400);
@include width-class(110);
```

This generates the following CSS:

```
.w400 {
  width: 400px; }

.w110 {
  width: 110px; }
```

Now, if you want to avoid writing a new `@include` line for each of the classes, you can create another mixins (or combine the two mixins into one):

```
@mixin dynwidths($size-list) {
  @each $size in $size-list {
    @include width-class($size)
  }
}
```

Now you can pass it a list of widths. This generates the same CSS as above:

```
@include width-classes(400 110);
```

---

Note: This is just a guess, but wildcard class names might be possible by extending Sass with Ruby. However, I'm not sure if this is a desirable feature.